# How to compare date field is lesser than today in record triggered flow?

Tags: criteria-filter, recordtriggeredflow

I have create record triggered flow in which i need to filter the records based on the below conditions

Status is equal to Done and Completion Date is lesser than  TODAY.

I am not able to obtain this in my flow, Please help me out !

[image]

Comment: Have you thought about using `{!$Flow.CurrentDate}` as the condition value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For record-triggered Flows, you cannot achieve such a filter so simply. You have 2 options:

1. Create a custom *Boolean* formula field on the SObject in question like `Completion Date < TODAY()` which would be set/reset for each record update. You can then check this conditional value in your Flow start condition i.e `is custom Boolean formula field Equals true`.
2. Use a single filter in your start condition (`Status is equal to Done`) and immediately after Flow start, add a condition block with the `Completion Date less than {!$Flow.CurrentDate}`.

Both options should be reviewed from a transactional POV on your behalf to see best fit.

Comment: Chose 2nd one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply create a formula field with return type checkbox, put in the condition - Completion Date < TODAY()  and use this field in the flow with condition is equal to true.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Your contributions are welcome, but I do not understand why you added as an answer the exact same information as found in #1 of the two-option answer originally given and accepted 10 months ago. Please see the note about "exact duplicates of other answers" in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) & be aware that your answer will likely be deleted. Please contribute to SFSE in other ways so that you gain reputation - you only need 15 rep to upvote an answer.